# Sed over BASH escaping

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking to go through our site and remove the encoded hard paths and replace them with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] over a shell connection, but I am not sure how to escape it correctly.

Need to replace

> `"/home/imprint/public_html/template`

With

> `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/template`

Here is what I found to do it, but I also need to include .htm files and I am not sure what I need to escape.

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/"/home/imprint/public_html/template/$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/template/g' {} \;
```

Also, what does the -i option do in sed?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine find clauses with `-o` ("or")
If you use different delimiters for the sed `s` command, you don't need to escape anything.

```
search='"/home/imprint/public_html/template'
replace='$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/template'

find . -name '*.php' -o -name '*.htm' \
       -exec sed -i "s#${search}#${replace}#g" {} +
```

To gain efficiency by reducing the number of times `sed` is invoked, use `-exec ... +` instead of `-exec ... \;`

Comment: This worked for finding them but then I get an error about command not found.
>find . \( -name '*.php' -o -name '*.htm' \)

Comment: Can you copy the command you used, plus the error message, into your question where it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're replacing a fixed string with another one, you can use sed with single quotes rather than doubles, as it will prevent any interpretation of the $ sign or other unpredicted funkiness.

Also since you're replacing pathes, fyi you can use other chars than / as sed's delimiter (i.e. `sed "s=abc=def=g"`), which is probably clearer.

From the man page :

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the next

```
shopt -s globstar
perl -i.bak -pe 's:/home/imprint/public_html/(template):\$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/$1:' ./**/*.php
```

- will create backup file `.bak`
- the `./**/*.php` will search for all php files recusively if the `globstar` option is set